# Manually changing line size in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Still getting to grips with ggplot. My question: How do I manually change the line size? I've tried with `scale_size_manual` but it didn't seem to work.

setup:

```
test.mat <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=32, ncol =3))
test.mat[,1] = rep(1:16,2)
test.mat[1:16,2] = as.character(rep("Cohort Alpha"),16)
test.mat[17:32,2] = as.character(rep("Factor Alpha"), 16)
test.mat[,3] = rnorm(32,0,1)
colnames(test.mat) = c("Window", "type", "value")

ggplot(test.mat, aes(x=Window, y=value)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = type, linetype = type)) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_colour_manual("type", values = c("black", "steelblue")) +
  scale_linetype_manual("type", values = c("solid", "solid")) +
  scale_size_manual("type", values = c(5, 1.4), guide = "none")
```

Comment: Maybe use `size` in geom_line? Most functions have a size argument anyways. Unless you have some other size mapping in mind, using the `size` arg should suffice.

Comment: @NelsonGon I have tried size = c(5,1.4)) but it doesn't work. Any suggestions

Comment: Your `scale_size_manual` is having no effect because you do not have a `size` aesthetic in your `ggplot`. Add `size=type` inside the `aes(...)` argument.

Comment: Try this: `iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, size=Species,
             y=Petal.Length,color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_size_manual(values=c(1,2,17))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

specify `size` inside aes() function as follows:

```
ggplot(test.mat, aes(x=Window, y=value)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = type, linetype = type, size = type)) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_colour_manual("type", values = c("black", "steelblue")) +
  scale_linetype_manual("type", values = c("solid", "solid")) +
  scale_size_manual("type", values = c(5, 1.4), guide = "none")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just turning @NelsonGon comment into an answer.

Is this what you want?

```r
test.mat <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=32, ncol =3))
test.mat[,1] = rep(1:16,2)
test.mat[1:16,2] = as.character(rep("Cohort Alpha"),16)
test.mat[17:32,2] = as.character(rep("Factor Alpha"), 16)
test.mat[,3] = rnorm(32,0,1)
colnames(test.mat) = c("Window", "type", "value")
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
base <- ggplot(test.mat, aes(x=Window, y=value)) 

#Here is where you need to add size  
line_size <- base + geom_line(aes(colour = type, linetype = type), size=3)
line_size + theme_classic() +
  scale_colour_manual("type", values = c("black", "steelblue")) +
  scale_linetype_manual("type", values = c("solid", "solid")) +
  scale_size_manual("type", values = c(5, 1.4), guide = "none")
```

## output

[image: output_nelson]

## Update

If you want variable thickness for the individual lines, you can do as follows.

```r
base <- ggplot(test.mat, aes(x=Window, y=value)) 
#Use an ifelse to add variable thickness 
line_size <- base + geom_line(aes(colour = type, size=ifelse(type=="Cohort Alpha",1,2)))

line_size + guides(size = FALSE)
```

[image: var_thickness]

Comment: I want any arbitrary difference in the line sizes. These look the same size to me?

Comment: This is creating a mapping for size aesthetic that is numeric, so a range of increasing sizes from 1 to 2 (likely counting by .2) is used, and only the thinnest and thickest are used. A discrete mapping could be made with ifelse(type=="Cohort Alpha","thin","thick) - BUT thin will only be thinner if it is the 1st observed level. You could use factor(ifelse(type=="Cohort Alpha","thin","thick"), levels=c("thick","thin") - BUT to specify the actual sizes you also need + scale_size_manual(values = c(1.8, .75)). Or other thick and thin size choices.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on my comment on deepseefan's answer

```
base + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = type, 
                size=factor(ifelse(type=="Cohort Alpha", "thick",  "thin"),
                            levels=c("thick","thin")))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "steelblue")) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(5, 1.4), guide = FALSE)
```